# How to fix "unable to locate package" for apt-get on Debian?

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to download/install packages on Debian 10 WSL, but I get an error:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
[sudo] password for admin:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cmake
```

I checked the **sources.list** file, and this is what it looks like:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

I notice that I'm not allowed to modify this document even though I've run my text editor in administrative mode: I get an error that the file is open in another program when it *visibly* isn't.

Taking a look at the docs and I've compared my one to the sample:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Is it fine to not have `deb-src` in my **sources.list**? I would try and modify the file, but I'm not allowed to.

**Update:** Doing apt-get update solved the "unable to locate package" problem.